# Find length of shortest path containing all 1s starting from top left in a binary matrix

Tags: python, algorithm, matrix, dynamic-programming, graph-theory

Given a matrix with 0s and 1s a cow wants to collect all 1s in the matrix starting from a corner (0,0). It can move up, down, left, right (unless at the edge of the matrix in which case it can't make the move to fall off). What is the length of the shortest path the cow can make?
Here is a brute force solution in Python:

```
import itertools
import sys

matrix = [[1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]
list = []
for x, i in enumerate(matrix):
    for y, j in enumerate(i):
        if j==1:
            list.append([x,y])
shortest = sys.maxint
for path in itertools.permutations(list):
   prev = [0,0]
   length = 0
   for element in path:
       length += abs(element[0]-prev[0]) + abs(element[1]-prev[1])
       prev = element
   if shortest > length:
       shortest = length
print shortest
```

This solution is taking O(*a*!) time where *a* is the number of 1s. So given the dimensions of the matrix is *nk* the upper bound we can give is O((*nk*)!).
I am looking for a way more efficient solution.

Comment: what are the maximum dimensions of grid and maximum number of ones ?

Comment: Assuming your "collect all 1s" means "visit all the nodes/elements that contain 1s", this seems to little more than a different way of describing the traveling salesman problem (for which factorial time is pretty much expected, unless you're willing to settle for an approximation of the best path).

Comment: _n_,_k_ <= 20, there is no upper bound to the number of 1s (apart from the 400 this bound implies)